# Azure pipeline template example

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Basically I wanted to reuse some common steps in one of my azure build pipeline definitions (a simple example being I have one copy file step and one command line step) that I want to reuse across several new build pipelines that I plan to create. Can I create these commonly used steps as a template and reuse them rather than manually creating them for every build definition I create?

I do know we can use templates to impose standards and security checks. But wanted to check if we can use this to combine frequently used steps across different build definitions. Acting as a single template and can be reused.

I also know we can easily achieve this via Task group but I wanted to create this as a yaml template so as to version control them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy content from one YAML and reuse it in a different YAMLs. This saves you from having to manually include the same logic in multiple places. The `include-steps.yml` file template contains steps that are reused in `azure-pipelines.yml`.

For example : First create a template yaml file(`include-steps.yml`) in your source repo.

```
# File: include-steps.yml
steps:
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(agent.builddirectory)'
    Contents: '**'
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script:   
      echo Hello world
```

Then reference this template.yml file in your `azure-pipelines.yml`.

```
# File: azure-pipelines.yml
jobs:
- job: Linux
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - template: templates/include-steps.yml  # Template reference
```

Comment: Can we reference different repos? I was reading about common template and it was mentioned to ave common template in a separate repo.

Comment: Of course.You can keep your templates in other repositories. For example, suppose you have a core pipeline that you want all of your app pipelines to use. You can put the template in a core repo and then refer to it from each of your app repos.For details ,please refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#use-other-repositories).